# How could I find someone to review puzzle products?

Tags: jigsaw-puzzle

I am Nabila from a toy company named Susengo. We manufucture puzzles, water toys and so on. In the few months, our company want to create and design several new jigsaw puzzles, so we need to listen to the consumers and get some sincere advice. But puzzling is a smaller hobby than others, so I don't know how to find those fans.

Or if I find, how could I successfully invite them to review?

Answer (score 3):

You could just as easily replace "puzzles" with pretty much any other product category and be asking the same question; your question is really about finding a focus group for your products, that just happen to be puzzles.

As with any product, knowing your market is important. I assume you already sell your products; there are probably a variety of different places where they are sold. If your company does online sales, you can reach your target audience pretty easily. If your products sell through smaller games and hobby shops, some of these might be a good place to go visit to see if you can find owners willing to let you post something up in their shop, or let you hand out flyers to customers, or any other practical outreach they'll agree to.

You can potentially also reach puzzle fans through advertisements in newsletters or forums where they hang out. (That doesn't mean it's ok to post *here* with a solicitation, as Stack Exchange isn't that kind of forum. Stack Exchange does accept paid advertisements, but I don't believe they do targeted ads on the Puzzling site.)

You'd probably get a better response elsewhere by asking this as a marketing question (that happens to be about puzzles), rather than trying to present it as a puzzles question (that happens to be about marketing to puzzle fans). As it is, this is just barely on topic for the Puzzling site, and unfortunately I don't see a Stack Exchange site for marketing, so you probably need to look elsewhere for more help.

Good luck!